# Iteration Summary app Rally SDK

Tags: javascript, sdk, rally

I'm using Rally SDK 1.33 with login key to create report pages. I need to display the Iteration Summary app outside of Rally. I've been trying to write this using the following to find information about the iterations in Rally:

```
    rallyDataSource.findAll({
          key: "sprints",
          type: "Iteration",
          query: '(EndDate > "today")',
          fetch: true
      }, displayIterationSummary);
```

The displayIterationSummary function would look something like this:

```
    function displayIterationSummary(results) {
           //access "Start Date" and "End Date" attribute from results.sprints to set up "DaysRemaining" and "TotalDays"
           var panelConfig = {
               title: "Sprint Summary",
               columnKeys: ['Name', 'DaysRemaining', 'TotalDays', 'State'],
               width: 600,
               height: 300

           };
           //take appropriate steps to display the result of this

       }
```

My thinking is that I can get the iteration "End Date" and "Start Date" with this and then I can use those attributes to set up a "Days Remaining" and "Total Days" attribute. How do I go about accessing these attributes inside the function "displayIterationSummary"? Also, if there is any other way to write and display the Iteration Summary app outside of Rally, please let me know! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that prints out a table of iterations with their StartDate, EndDate and some other data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Copyright (c) 2010  Rally Software Development Corp.  All rights reserved -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table Component Example</title>
    <meta name="Name"    content="App Example: Table of Iterations" />
    <meta name="Version" content="2010.4" />
    <meta name="Vendor"  content="Rally Lab - Nick" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.33/sdk.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function tableExample() {
            var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('1111', '22222',
            'false', 'true');
            function itemQuery() {
                var queryObject = {
                    key: 'it',
                    type: 'iteration',
                    fetch: 'Name,ObjectID,Project,StartDate,EndDate',
                    query:'(EndDate > Today)'
                };
                rallyDataSource.findAll(queryObject, populateTable);
            }

            function populateTable(results) {

                for (var i=0; i < results.it.length; i++) {
                    results.it[i].Difference = rally.sdk.util.DateTime.getDifference(new Date(rally.sdk.util.DateTime.
                    fromIsoString(results.it[i].EndDate)),new Date(rally.sdk.util.DateTime.
                    fromIsoString(results.it[i].StartDate, "day")));
                }

                var tableDiv = document.getElementById('aDiv');
                if(table) {
                    table.destroy();
                }
                var config = { 
                    columns:
                    [
                        {key: 'Name'},
                        {key: 'ObjectID'},
                        {key: 'StartDate'},
                        {key: 'EndDate'},
                        {key: 'Difference'},
                        {key: 'Project.Name'}
                    ]
                };
                var table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(config);
                table.addRows(results.it);
                table.display(tableDiv);

            };
            itemQuery();
        }

        rally.addOnLoad(tableExample);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="aDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

To run an app outside of Rally, e.g. directly in the browser, a full URL to sdk.js is required:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.33/sdk.js"></script>
```

[This document](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps-outside-rally) describes how to run apps outside of Rally
It is not necessary to use LoginKey in order to run apps outside of Rally. LoginKey functionality allows to run custom apps or standard reports without being prompted to login to Rally since it has a read-only user's credentials encoded.

Comment: Right, I have another table that basically does what you've done here. What I want to know is, inside your populateTable function can you perform operations (like getting the difference between StartDate and EndDate) and somehow get that to display in your table?

Comment: For example: (in a nested loop)  table.setCell(i, j, rally.sdk.util.DateTime.getDifference(new Date(results.sprints.EndDate), new Date(results.sprints.StartDate), "day")); //this doesn't work of course, but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do

Comment: I modified a code to include a column called "Difference" (you may name it anything) and added this loop:                           for (var i=0; i < results.it.length; i++) {
   results.it[i].Difference = rally.sdk.util.DateTime.getDifference(new Date(rally.sdk.util.DateTime.
   fromIsoString(results.it[i].EndDate)),new Date(rally.sdk.util.DateTime.
   fromIsoString(results.it[i].StartDate, "day")));
  }